# Translating C to assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

In my course notes, I've got this info:

C:

```
thisthread.id = 4711;
```

Assembler:

```
.text
.align 2
movia r8,thisthread
movi r9,4711
stw r9,4(r8) # id after sp that takes 4 bytes
```

But doesn't sp take 4 bits instead? I thought the offset was specified in bits, not in bytes. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Well, the only way to manipulate bits is to use bit operators. Usually memory can't be adressed by bits.

Comment: If SP is stack pointer, then it's size being 4 bits would limit usable stack to 16 bytes, which would be of no use (as this is space for local variables, for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mistaken. The offset is indeed in bytes.